# Being able to read images from any directory

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm new to Matlab and I am having some problems with reading images and dealing with directories and things like that. I had an assignment where I was to write a script that converts an image that is not grayscale into grayscale (for example, if the image is truecolor, convert to grayscale).

This was my code:

```
img = uigetfile('*');
imgx = imfinfo(img);


imgx.ColorType
if imgx.ColorType == 'truecolor'
   img = imread(img);
   img = rgb2gray(img);
end
```

However, I ended up getting points off for the following:

"only works if image is in the same folder as script"

I realize that my script only works for images that are in folders that are on the MATLAB path, so I don't know if that's a separate issue from what he said or if that's what he meant. I assume he wants to be able to select any image on your computer to be able to read and perform the operation, but I don't know how to approach this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `img = uigetfile('*')` returns only the file name as string. To work with pictures in folders other than matlab folder you would need to extract the full path. You can do this using the following approach:

```
[fileName, folderName] = uigetfile('*');
img=fullfile(folderName, fileName);
imgx = imfinfo(img);
```

The rest of your code should work after this small change